# Error when installing my application on my device

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio-3.0

when I try to install the application on genymotion it runs without problems but when I try to install it on my physical device I get this error

```
Installation did not succeed.
The application could not be installed.
Installation failed due to: ''pm install-create -r -t -S 4930945' returns error 'Unknown         
failure: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for java.lang.String 
android.os.SystemProperties.native_get(java.lang.String) (tried 
Java_android_os_SystemProperties_native_1get and         
Java_android_os_SystemProperties_native_1get__Ljava_lang_String_2)
at android.os.SystemProperties.native_get(Native Method)
at android.os.SystemProperties.get(SystemProperties.java:52)
at android.os.Environment.getCanonicalPathOrNull(Environment.java:832)
at android.os.Environment.<clinit>(Environment.java:83)
at android.os.Environment.getLegacyExternalStorageDirectory(Environment.java:419)
at android.os.Debug.<clinit>(Debug.java:101)
at android.ddm.DdmHandleHello.handleHELO(DdmHandleHello.java:164)
at android.ddm.DdmHandleHello.handleChunk(DdmHandleHello.java:91)
at org.apache.harmony.dalvik.ddmc.DdmServer.dispatch(DdmServer.java:171)
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: android.os.Debug
at android.ddm.DdmHandleHello.handleFEAT(DdmHandleHello.java:176)
at android.ddm.DdmHandleHello.handleChunk(DdmHandleHello.java:93)
at org.apache.harmony.dalvik.ddmc.DdmServer.dispatch(DdmServer.java:171)
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: android.os.Debug
at android.ddm.DdmHandleProfiling.handleMPRQ(DdmHandleProfiling.java:187)
at android.ddm.DdmHandleProfiling.handleChunk(DdmHandleProfiling.java:88)
at org.apache.harmony.dalvik.ddmc.DdmServer.dispatch(DdmServer.java:171)
```

here is my code
https://github.com/AbdallahNaguib/Images-Loader

android version of my device is 5.1
my android studio version is 3.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switch off the "Verify Apps over USB" in the "Developer Options". If it does not work then try Revoke USB debugging authorizations in the Developer Options

Comment: "Verify Apps over USB" was already off , and when i tried to Revoke USB debugging authorizations , I still get the same error